# How to click on a link in web table using cypress for which I am getting message element not visible because it's CSS property is display: none

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation, mouseclick-event

I have a web table and I have to click on first link which is enabled in 'Action' column. So in this example first two rows does not have link enabled, so I have to click on '8.5 AccountH'

[image]

When I inspect this element then following is the HTML for it

[image]

I have tried many solutions and some of them are as follow: -

```
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td').find('span.link').eq(1).click()
OR
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td i.far.check.fa-square').next().click()
OR
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td').find('span.link').eq(1).click({force:true})
OR
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td').find('span.link').first().click()
```

But none is working. It would be great if community helps me in resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

Since events bubble, you can try clicking on the cell and the link should respond.

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td').click()
```

#### Select by cell content

Using text in the cell to select is a stronger selector.

```js
cy.contains('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td', 'Prior 3 months data')
  .click()
```

#### Select first enabled row

Using `:enabled` pseudo selector, there's a few possible options to try

***Note: you may have to examine the "row" element to choose a suitable selector - the key thing is to append `:enabled` to the row selector.***

**Clicking row**

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table')
  .find('.tr:enabled').first()    // first enabled row (not sure what selector to use)
  .click()                        // click the row
```

**Clicking cell**

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table')
  .find('.tr:enabled').first()               // first enabled row
  .find('.td.check-td')                      // checkbox cell
  .next()                                   // next cell
  .click()
```

**Clicking span with toggle-group**

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table')
  .find('.tr:enabled').first()               // first enabled row
  .find('.td.check-td')                      // checkbox cell
  .next()                                   // next cell
  .find('span.toggle-group')                
  .click({force:true})                      // force because hidden
```

**Clicking span with description**

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table')
  .find('tr:enabled').first()               // first enabled row
  .find('td.check-td')                      // checkbox cell
  .next()                                   // next cell
  .find('span.toggle-group')                
  .next()
  .click()
```

---

Ref [MDN Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Example diagram:

[image]

Comment: Hi @fody, thanks for your help but none of the solution is working.

Comment: Some more options added.

Comment: Hi @fody, problem here is we don't have td & tr tags for rows and columns rather we have div. So this solution does not work. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Oh yes I noticed that originally but forgot it on the revision. But you have classes named `td` so for cells just change to `.find('.td.check-td')`. Can't see the parent element of the cells, but maybe it has `class="tr"` so you can do the same thing there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `force: true` it should work.

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td')
  .find('span.link')
  .eq(0)
  .click({force: true})
```

OR

```js
cy.get('.data-table-ctn.mb-3 .data-table div.td')
  .find('span.link')
  .first()
  .click({force: true})
```

OR, You can directly use the content and click it, something like:

```js
cy.contains(
  'span.link',
  'AccountHolder Consumer Lending Postgre Move- Prior 3 months data'
).click()
```

Comment: Hi Alapan, thanks for your response but none of the solution working as 'display:none'

Comment: `{force: true}` should work with `display:none`. Try it once with the `contains`

Comment: Hi Alapan, this table is quite dynamic therefore rows keep changing and hence text in column 'Action' also change time and again. So contains doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```js
cy.get('.your-link-selector:visible')
```

If you want it to be more readable with cypress commands you can use `.filter()`

```js
cy.get('.your-linke-selector')
  .filter(':visible')
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but it is not working.

Comment: It might be your selector you are using. Showing more HTML of the table would help.